# SAPUI5 : Table search field not working on defined values

Tags: sapui5

I have a parameter **Type** which is coming as **Integer**. If **Type** is **0** we show "**Protect**" otherwise **Unprotect**
My Controller is something like this

```
    new Column({
        label: new Label({text: "Type"}),
        template: new Label({text:
                {
                    path: "ruleType",
                    formatter: function (value) {
                            if(parseInt(value)  === 0)
                                return "Protect";
                            else
                                return "Unprotect";
                        }
                }}),
        filterProperty: "ruleType"
    })
```

My View is something like this

```
    var vQuery = oEvent.getParameter("searchparam");
    new Filter({
        path: 'ruleType',
        operator: FilterOperator.Contains,
        value1: vQuery
    }),
```

I have 2 issues

1. Uncaught Error: Only "String" values are supported for the FilterOperator: "Contains".
2. When I search with search value : "Protect" filter is not working.

I tried changing FilterOperator.Contains to FilterOperator.EQ  string error is gone but search with "Protect" is not working. Can someone help

Comment: provide a plunkr or fiddle, that would be easier to provide a solution.

Comment: @santhosh : It will be difficult for me, since i am new to this framework. Please try to give the solution from given description

Comment: In odata context, the comparator "contains" isn't supported by integer. Use EQ, GT etc.

Comment: Filter is working with integer, Filter should work on Protect/ Unprotect. Is that possible ?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a custom test function (I always convert the string and search query to lower case).

```
var vQuery = oEvent.getParameter("searchparam").toLowerCase();

new Filter({
        path: 'ruleType',
        test: function(value){ 
            return value.toLowerCase().indexOf(vQuery) > -1 //returns true/false
      }
});
```

Comment: Value is coming in integer, toLowerCase dont work

Comment: this issue is fixed, we have created a new property eg : ruleTypelabel and updated the object and used in the filter